# Onclick close a modal in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and created a custom dialog box, now i want to close the modal when i click on <CloseIcon icon. I tried to use useState but it did not worked. want a simple solution for my functional component.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { ProjectsContext, actions } from '../../context';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import {
  InputLabel,
} from 'components'
import styles from './index.module.scss';
import {
  Close as CloseIcon
} from '@material-ui/icons';
const GdmComments = (props) => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(ProjectsContext);
  console.log(props);

  //const [removeSection, selectState] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className={props.active ? `${styles.activeState} ${styles.commentSection}` : styles.commentSection} >
      <div className={styles.commentHeader}>
        GDM Comments
            <CloseIcon className={styles.cursor} onClick={props.resolveState}/>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.secBody}>

        <InputLabel>Add Comments</InputLabel>

        <div>
          {
            state.gdmListInfo.gdmCommentList ? state.gdmListInfo.gdmCommentList.map(function (item) {
              return (
                <div>
                  <div className={styles.commentArea}>{item.comment.toString()}</div>
                  <span className={styles.date}>{item.at.toString() ? format(new Date(item.at || null), 'dd MMM yyyy') : '-'}</span>
                </div>
              )
            }) : null
          }
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


  )
}

export default GdmComments;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<CloseIcon className={styles.cursor} onClick={props.resolveState}/>
```

Change this to

```
<CloseIcon className={styles.cursor} onClick={() => {props.resolveState({active: false})}}/>
```

On receiving end of the callback function use the active property returned to hide or show the modal.

If `props.resolveState` is not used anywhere else apart from closing the modal, just send false. On receiving set active to false.